# how struts understand which is model and which is controller?

Tags: java, struts

my manager classes and data Access Object (DAO) classes are in model group of Model view Control then how struts understand which is model and which is controller?

Answer (score 0):

In struts if you are extending the Action Class, Struts will automatically consider it as an Action Object i.e. the Controller and within this you call call your manager/helperClasses's methods. 
The flow is  :: 
The framework(RequestDispatcher) will call the execute method of your Action Class, by creating a reference of Action class and instantiate your action class mentioned in struts-config.xml.
Hope this was usefull.